# What's the best way to create header panel for Android app?

Tags: android, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

What's the best way to create header panel for my app? I want to have something like this:
[app_example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkSd9.png)

Instead of "ChrunchifyCalculator" I need to place there my app icon and name.

This is my solution structure:
[solution_structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/agSlk.png)

Should I use Toolbar.xml from testHeader.Android -> Resources or it's not the right way?

Comment: I have no idea about xamarin. 
But in Android studio, you can add textview, imageview on toolbar in layout xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize the toolbar by using `NavigationPage.TitleView`.
You can even add header-bar (Status Bar) from the resource file of the Droid project.

> Use the below snippet for adding Customised Header.

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             .
             .
             .>

    <NavigationPage.TitleView>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="8*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Icon source="YOUR_ICON.png" Grid.Column="0"/>
            <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="APP_NAME" TextColor="#ffffff" FontSize="Large" HorizontalOptions="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
        </Grid>
    </NavigationPage.TitleView>

    <ContentPage.Content>

              <-- YOUR XAML CODE -->

    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```